# Malformed bower.json file

Tags: json, bower

I have the latest version of Bower installed. I am trying the command

```
bower register flatly-3 https://github.com/brandonjschwartz/bower-bootswatch-flatly.git
```

Bower has the error message that the bower.json file is malformed due to an unexpected string. I have tried a number of different things (punctuation etc) but get the same error... Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower is attempting to get tag 3.0.0 from your repo:

https://github.com/brandonjschwartz/bower-bootswatch-flatly/releases/tag/3.0.0

The bower.json from that release does have some issues:

```
{
  "name": "bower-bootswatch-flatly",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "main": "less/flatly.less",
  "keywords": [
    "flatly",
    "bootstrap",
    "twitter bootstrap",
    "bootswatch",
    "less",
    "css",
    "flat",
    "flat ui",
    "theme"
  ] <-- missing comma
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-less": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Your best bet is to redo the tag